How to detect which physical interface an IP is being reached through in a network bridge?
I have the linked network setup. network diagram

In essence, there is a router that manages DHCP and broadcasts Wifi A, then there is a dedicated access point that broadcasts Wifi B.  A station connects via layer 2 to one or both, but via a Linux network bond interface in active-backup mode which only chooses one Wifi at a time to direct data through. I am using static IPs.
The dedicated access point has a bridge interface between the router and the station, as it is my goal to make this access point transparent in the layer 3 organization of the network. However, I do need to detect from the access point which link is currently being used to communicate with the station, either Wifi A or Wifi B.
I have investigated using ip route get however it returns my bridge br0. I would like to figure out whether communication to the station IP is being done through the ethernet to the router, and subsequently Wifi A, or directly through Wifi B.
I may also be confusing the layer 2 and 3 intricacies of the network here.  My main goal is just to understand the bonding mode of the station from the access point.
TLDR: How can one see which part of a network bridge an IP address can be reached through?

Why do you care?

I need applications to change the amount of data being sent to the station if it is using Wifi B, as wifi B is 802.11ah and therefore has low throughput.

Can you throttle at a higher level, e.g. have your application monitor throughput? Or perhaps make it two different L3 networks?

I do worry for L3 that I would need to consider how to make the station addressable with the same IP across the various devices.  I will look into throughput monitoring.

How? Depends on what the business-related question or issue is here. the usual tools like ifstat can tell, but moreover in a bridge setup, which bridge mode has been used. since you're hiding any part of a configuration and also what goal you want to reach, it's hard to tell. and Still the question is, why is it important?

The application here is a pit crew telemetry system for a racecar (the racecar is the station).  It will often go out of range of Wifi A as it is 2.4ghz, and switch to Wifi B, 900mhz.  At that switch the station limits data sent.  The router-side telemetry system records times at which it is at 900mhz, so that it understands the station is sending less data, and alerts any telemetery reading clients that limited data is being sent.  However, I do not want to get this info from the station in case the station becomes disconnected or otherwise fails, I want this to be a router side operation.

Since you're bridging it's not a routing but a bridging/switching guestion really.

via a Linux network bond interface in active-backup mode

So it's for the client to decide which interface is in active mode and receives all data.
The router resolves the client IP for the MAC of its active interface and then sends the encapsulating frame to that interface.

I do need to detect from the access point which link is currently being used

Since it is bridging, the access point can see where the client's MAC is associated - either to its Ethernet (via Wifi-A) or its Wifi interface (via Wifi-B).

fail_over_mac active turned on the dynamic mac for the bond interface, then specifying both MAC addrs for Wifi A and B in the dhcp configuration of the router allowed for a static lease to work.  Thanks!
